# Credential editing in Plist if Correct

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

In plist I have stored Credentials from that I need to check for the correct Credential  and if the correct Credential match then replace the password field with the new..for this I Have 3 `UITextField` . A for new email-id ,b for current password and c for new password ..if `a==b` means `current password == email id` then new password entered in the c textfield should replace in the current password field in `plist`
[image: eneter here]
.

```
 - (void)authenticateCredentials {
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self readFromPlist]];

for (int i = 0; i< [plistArray count]; i++)
{
    id object = [plistArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;

        if ([[objDict objectForKey:@"pass"] isEqualToString:emailTextFeild.text] && [[objDict objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:passwordTextFeild.text])
        {

            NSLog(@"Correct credentials");
            // what should be the condition to replace current password to new password
        }
        NSLog(@"INCorrect credentials");
    } else {
         NSLog(@"Error! Not a dictionary");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this will work for you.

```
- (void)authenticateCredentials {

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XYZ.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];
    NSArray *plistArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSMutableArray *plistUpdatedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:plistArray];

    for (int i = 0; i< [plistArray count]; i++)
    {
        id object = [plistArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;

            if ([[objDict objectForKey:@"pass"] isEqualToString:emailTextFeild.text] && [[objDict objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:passwordTextFeild.text])
            {
                NSLog(@"Correct credentials");

                NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:objDict];
                [dict1 setObject:newPassword forKey:@"title"];

                [plistUpdatedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dict1];

                NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
                [dict2 setObject:plistUpdatedArray forKey:@"title"];
                [dict2 writeToFile:documentPlistPath atomically:YES];

                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"INCorrect credentials");
        } else {
             NSLog(@"Error! Not a dictionary");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i need your help regarding the same plist .. in some other screen I have to fetch the emaild -id of the logged-In user and to display in the label .....I have taken Readplist function  in new screen now how to call take email-id of the logged in user

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950903/how-to-fetch-data-from-plist-in-label check this link

Answer (score 1):

If your plist is in bundle you can't change the value stored in it.
So copy it to document directory before doing any change.

Answer to your question:

```
if([emailField.text isEqualToString:currntPwd.txt])
{
   NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:objDict];
  [newDict setObject:@"Midhun" forKey:@"pass"];
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *plistPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlist.plist"];
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath];
   [newDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```